# shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0} Error: Not Found Error: Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

So i was working with github workflows.
I am having issue while executing the yml file i am getting issue.

> shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
> Error: Not Found
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I have tried changing the value with a different one and tried by changing the version of the node.

**WORKFLOW FILE CODE**

name: Deploy

on:

```
workflow_dispatch:
push:
branches:
  - main
```

jobs:

update-readme:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:

  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Use Node.js 18
    uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: 18
    
  - name: Install Dependencies
    run: npm install @octokit/rest node-fetch

  - name: Run script to update README table
    run: |
      node .github/workflows/github_trigger_script.js

  - name: Update README
    run: |
      dynamic_content="This content is dynamically generated."

      sed -i "s/{{DYNAMIC_CONTENT}}/$dynamic_content/g" README.md

      git config --global user.name "sushantAtwork"
      git config --global user.email "sushant.raj@netsmartz.net"

      git add README.md
      git commit -m "Update README table with new branch info"
      git push origin HEAD:main

    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TEST_REPO }}
```

[Repo Link](https://github.com/sushantAtwork/back_end_trigger/actions/workflows/master.yml)